# Display div upon hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a `div` display when hovering over an `a` tag. I also want the `div` to not disappear when the mouse moves onto the displayed `div`. Although I want the `div` to disappear when you aren't hovering on the `a` tag text or the `div` itself.

This is being specifically used for a navigation bar that can display content on one of the `tabs` when hovering over it.

I have tried using the `.div-name + .div-name2 {}` method, but since I have content between these two `divs`, this solution does not work.

If there is a better way of doing this e.g. through some sort of bootstrap mechanic, that would be great to know as well as I am sure I am over-complicating this using javascript and jquery. Otherwise helping me with the javascript/jquery would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(".hover-btn").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".hover-btn-section").stop().fadeIn(500);
});

$(".hover-btn").mouseleave(function() {
  $(".hover-btn-section").stop().delay(500).fadeOut(500);
});

$(".hover-btn-section").mouseenter(function() {
  $(".hover-btn-section").stop();
});
```

```css
.hover-btn {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hover-btn-section {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class='hover-btn'>hover-btn</a>
<a href="#" class='link2'>link2</a>

<div class="hover-btn-section">
  <p>Testing Area</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe can be achieved using CSS only. Instead of the adjacent sibling selector `+` use the sibling selector `~`:

```css
.hover-btn {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.hover-btn:hover ~ .hover-btn-section {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}

.hover-btn-section {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  background-color: yellow;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}

.hover-btn-section:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: all;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hover-btn">hover-btn</a>
<a href="#" class="link2">link2</a>

<div class="hover-btn-section">
  <p>Testing Area</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer works great! Although just out of curiosity on line 2 of your html the * is a typo right? Just double checking.

Comment: Haha sorry my bad, I made a typo, thanks i'll edit question.